# How to open git local documentation files by git command?

Tags: git

Working with git branch I press this git command `git branch --help` , and it open a nice doc file from my computer where git was installed. Like this —

[image]

and scroll down I also found this nice doc as well

[image]

In the URL if I paste this **file:///C:/Program%20Files/Git/mingw64/share/doc/git-doc/** then show this almost all doc about git. Like this —

[image]

My question is, if `git branch --help` show the branch-related doc then how to open all doc section by git command, which I share by screenshot number 3. Can anybody know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to open the listing of all HTML pages in the browser like this.  The reason is that the `--help` functionality can display in various formats, only one of which is HTML.

The default behavior on many systems is to display a manual page, and typically all manual pages from all programs on the system are stored in the same directory.  Therefore, there's no place to show only the Git docs in general, and as such, Git doesn't provide an option to do this.

If you just want to see a list of all the commands, `git help -a` will do that, though, and then you can run `git help COMMAND`.  `git help --help` will show you all of the available options you can use.